# Angular 4 app error after deployment to aws S3 - "TypeError QueueScheduler_1.QueueScheduler is not a constructor"

Tags: angular

I have a angular 4 project

it runs fine locally, and on aws S3
however i pushed recent changes and deployed to S3 again

i navigate to the home page i get this error on the browser console,

```
queue.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: QueueScheduler_1.QueueScheduler is not a constructor
at Object.<anonymous> (queue.js:65)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8e4fbe1…:52)
at Object.<anonymous> (ReplaySubject.js:8)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8e4fbe1…:52)
at Object.<anonymous> (WebSocketSubject.js:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8e4fbe1…:52)
at Object.<anonymous> (webSocket.js:2)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8e4fbe1…:52)
at Object.<anonymous> (webSocket.js:3)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8e4fbe1…:52)
```

I haven't used QueueScheduler in my code
the project runs locally but the error remains on S3